# Magento backend can't browse,upload, or select images when editing or creating products

Tags: magento

The Magento Version that I'm using is 1.7.0.2

My problem is that when I go to create or edit a product and I select "Images" under 
"Product Information" all I get is a line that says "Images".

Underneath the line that says "Images" I'm supposed to get a table with radio buttons, and two other buttons that say "Browse Files" and "Upload Files", but I don't.

Anyone have an idea as to how to solve this issue?

Edit:
I also just noticed that I'm missing everything under Inventory and Categories.
There's also some broken buttons, such as the Save Attribute button.

Comment: is there any js error in browser?

Comment: @KeyurShah Not that I know of. Is there a way to check?

Comment: @Marius I have upgraded flash player and I get this same problem on other computers as well.